# Records listed per page in Yii

Tags: php, frameworks, yii

I am a beginner in Yii. I am using the views/myModel/index.php page to list all records in the MySQL table. By default the number of records displayed per page is 10. How can I change it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all model folder should not contain index.php. this folder contains all classes related with your database tables(CActiveRecords) and other models.

for increasing number of records per page you can set pagesize of pagination in CGridView or CListView.

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Invoice',
        array(
            'criteria'=>array(
                'with'=>array('client'),
                'condition'=>'businessId='. Yii::app()->userInfo->business,
            ),
            'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>20,),

        )
    );


            $this->render('index',array(
                    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
            ));
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I meant the name of the model by model in model/index.php

Comment: So if I wish to only change the pageSize `'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>8)` would do right ?
I tried that and it rolls exception _"CDbCriteria.pagenation" is not defined._

Comment: pagination is a property of CActiveDataProvider class. Ignoring the criterea property solved the issue.

Comment: I believe this answer has a typo in it.  As written, it makes it look like `pagination` is a property of `criteria`, when in fact it is a property of the CActiveDataProvider itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do something like this in your code:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;

$criteria->condition = "...";
$criteria->params = array();
$criteria->limit = 20;
$criteria->offset  = 0;
$records = YourModel::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

Where limit is the number of records to show per page and offset is where the record number start, which you can use as your page number.